# Comandos Básicos

Tags: sql

Boa tarde.

Sou novo com Banco de Dados e não consigo resolver essa solução

Monte uma cláusula que realize UPDATE, para todos os funcionários que exercem a função “Programador de Computador”, mudando sua função para “Gerente de programação”

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Update NOME DA SUA TABELA
set NOME DA COLUNA = "Gerente de programação"
Where NOME DA COLUNA  = "Programador de Computador";

Comment: Bem-vindo! [Faça o tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e conheça o StackOverflow em português.

Comment: @JoãoVitorCastilhoGamba É preferível que você adicione estas informações na própria pergunta ao invés de espalhá-la pelos comentários. Basta clicar em **[edit]** (logo abaixo da pergunta) e adicionar as informações. Veja também [este link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), que dá dicas de como formatar o código na pergunta.

Comment: @hkotsubo pronto está editado.

Answer (score 2):

Como não foi passado nenhuma informação da estrutura do caso, um exemplo mais "padronizado" pra sanar a dúvida seria:

`UPDATE funcionario SET funcao = 'Gerente de programação' WHERE funcao = 'Programador de Computador'`.

O `SET`vai atribuir o valor desejado no campo informado e o `WHERE` filtrará quais registros sofrerão a alteração de acordo com a condição informada.

Comment: No caso duas Tabelas. Uma chama Funcionário e nessa contem a coluna CdFunção. A outra tabela chama Função e nessa tem a coluna DescFunção

Comment: Poderia editar a pergunta ou comentar os detalhes da estrutura, como os nomes e os tipos dos campos dessas tabelas? Assim você será melhor respondido.

Comment: O nome da tabela é assim mesmo? Com acento e tudo? E como é a tabela de funções?